# Neoj4 native driver vs REST

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently working with Neo4J with the neo4jclient library for .net (https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki)

This however is a library that uses the REST capabilities of Neo4j. Now I am wondering if this isn't a performance issue compared to for example something like the Java JDBC-drivers (http://neo4j.com/developer/java/).

The applications I will be developing will be real-time and should be performant (noticable delays are not acceptable).

Comment: for realtime and performant applications, depending of your use cases and features, you'll better write a neo4j plugin that your client will consume.

Comment: I think it depends on the application.  You can go pretty far by using cypher queries to get exactly what you need.  But yes, after a certain point writing an unmanaged extension makes sense http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Comment: I don't know that there's enough information to answer this question